# Switching childs-of-childs in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Firebase image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkc1Q.png)

To help your understanding, I provided an image with easy key names and values according to the Database Reference's child.

I'm looking to switch two childs' values+keys

For example, Child 0 has the new child "keyOne" with the key being "keyOne" and the value being "valueOne"... Etc with Child 1, 2, and 3.

### -

How would I go about switching the childs of "0" and "1"?

By switching childs, I mean I want to end up with.

### -

```
0 -> keyOne: valueOne

1 -> keyZero: valueZero
```

Hopefully you guys understand what I mean. If you haven't by now, I'll give it one last shot!

I'm looking to switch the key+value combination of a child with the key+value combo of ANOTHER child.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `currentMembers` node is a direct child of your Firebase root and your database looks like this:

[image]

To achieve what you want, please the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference currentMembersRef = rootRef.child("currentMembers");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String valueZero =  dataSnapshot.child("0").child("keyZero").getValue(String.class);
        String valueOne =  dataSnapshot.child("1").child("keyOne").getValue(String.class);

        dataSnapshot.child("0").child("keyZero").getRef().setValue(valueOne);
        dataSnapshot.child("1").child("keyOne").getRef().setValue(valueZero);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
currentMembersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result will be:

[image]

Comment: I have! The only problem with this solution (thanks for responding by the way) is the value being the only thing that changes. I was looking for both the key and value (etc. keyZero + valueZero) to change as a "pair". Think of it as a username and a full name switching between the ranks  of a list ("currentMembers"). My goal is to switch both the username and full name together inside childs (if that makes any sense). Try reading my question again? Thank you though. @Alex Mamo

Comment: There is no way in Firebase in which you can change the name of a key. There is no API for doing that. If you need to change the name a of key, you need to make copy of that child, change the name and remove the old one. A solution for what you are trying to do is to create a ranking system and then just query your data acccording to it. Even if it was possible to rename a key, it would not have helped you at all. The order in the database is not the order in your output.

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you?